Reply to a direct message and mark conversation as read
I've been able to success connect to Facebook Graph API for Instagram and now I have all messages and conversations stored and I also can send messages to any user I want, but, I'm trying to find two endpoints that seems impossible to:

An endpoint or param to REPLY to a specific direct message, not just send a message to the user.
An endpoint or param to mark a conversation as read, because besides I'm sending DMs via API, in the app the conversation still marked as unread.

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks!
I've tried to use Facebook endpoints but didn't worked, I also tried to copy Whatsapp but again it failed.
